# Processes are closing after removing the SD card

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, sd-card, force-close, processes

I have removed the SD card from my phone and now my phone is not working.

All phone related processes are force closing. I have cleaned my cache and did 'Fix Permission' via Recovery but the processes are still force closing.

I have installed and customized a number of apps and I don't want to Factory Reset it. Is there an option to fix the issue without doing factory reset?

- Getting the same SD card content back is not an option since the card was formatted.
- My phone is Huawei Honor 3C and I am using TWRP recovery on it.
- I have already checked all the questions here: https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=SD+Card+Removed+Unexpectedly

Update:
The problem is back after inserting the SIM card. I cleared cache/data of Phone and SIM Toolkit but the issue is still there.

2nd Update:
I installed a new ROM since there's no help available.

Comment: Did you setup it up to install from SD card? Normally when you pull the SD card and things don't go right, it's because the data was transfered over to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself without removing anything.

Step-by-step info is written below:

1. Remove your sim card
2. Boot into recovery
3. Clear your cache
4. Click on that beautiful 'Fix Permission' button
5. Turn on your phone
6. If everything works fine 'Continue' (otherwise repeat steps 1-5 again)
7. Turn Off your phone
8. Put the sim card back
9. Enjoy your phone

*Update:
The problem is back after inserting the SIM card.

Answer (score 0):

You should try Clear Data for the relevant apps.  If that doesn't work, I do think that your only real option is a factory reset (which is more or less like a Clear Data for everything on the phone).  If you are rooted you can back up yours apps and data, and after the factory reset you can restore one app at a time — if there are no issues, great, but if there are then you know exactly what app/data caused the issue.